# Android: Problema con Listview y CursorAdapter

Tags: java, android

Estoy probando la carga de una base de datos (SQLite) a un ListView usando un CursorAdapter.

Desde MainActivity puedo acceder sin problemas a los datos de la base de datos. El problema está en que cuando llama al adaptador se cuelga la aplicación.

Aquí dejo el código:

main.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layFondo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.milista4.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTituloSupreior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="33sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txtNombre"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:text="Nombre" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txtApellido"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:text="Apellido" />"

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnBoton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="B" />"


</LinearLayout>
```

Adaptador.java :

```
    package com.example.milista5;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Adaptador extends CursorAdapter {

        public Adaptador(Activity context, Cursor cursor) {

            super(context, cursor, 0);


        }


        @Override

        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

            return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        }

      @Override

        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {



          // Find fields to populate in inflated template

          TextView tNombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);

          TextView tApellido = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtApellido);

          tNombre.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Nombre")));

          tApellido.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Apellido")));

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.milista5;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView txtSup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTituloSupreior);

        ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);



        SQLiteDatabase db;

        db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Mi_Database", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        /*db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Personas (Nombre VARCHAR, Apellido VARCHAR)");

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Personas (Nombre, Apellido) VALUES ('Francisco', 'Profiti')");*/

        Cursor miCursor;

        miCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Personas" , null);

        miCursor.moveToFirst();

        Adaptador miAdaptador = new Adaptador(this, miCursor);

        lista.setAdapter(miAdaptador);

        db.close();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

El Logcat :

```
10-19 00:02:22.751: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(531): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Personas, db=/data/data/com.example.milista5/databases/Mi_Database
10-19 00:02:22.751: D/AndroidRuntime(531): Shutting down VM
10-19 00:02:22.761: W/dalvikvm(531): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.milista5/com.example.milista5.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Personas: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Personas
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Personas: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Personas
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1538)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at com.example.milista5.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
10-19 00:02:22.770: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Hola @JuCaMa. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrás compartir el logcat de cuando se cuelga?

Comment: @JuCaMa., como comenta Mariano, esta pregunta puede tener muchas respuestas posibles, es importante que si desarrollas aplicaciones Android tengas presente la importancia del uso del LogCat, esto te ahorrara mucho tiempo solucionando problemas en tu aplicación.

Comment: Aqui esta el Logcat

Comment: @JuCaMa gracias, he agregado una respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 3):

JuCaMa., gracias por agregar tu mensaje de LogCat, en base a esto determinamos el problema:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Personas: ,
>   while compiling: SELECT * FROM Personas 10-19 00:02:22.770:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)

Estas realizando un query:

```
miCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Personas" , null);
```

pero la tabla `Personas` no existe!

---

Las lineas que comentaste son las que realizan la creacion de la tabla en la base de datos.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Personas (Nombre VARCHAR, Apellido VARCHAR)");

db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Personas (Nombre, Apellido) VALUES ('Francisco', 'Profiti')");
```

Comment: Como dice @Elenasys el problema radica en que no encuentra la tabla Personas, ya sea porque no está creada o porque la hayas creado con otro nombre, revisa bien la creación de la tabla.